# npm install mongoose get error on windows 7

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can anyone help me fix this error I'm getting when installing mongoose.js?  I'm trying to install Mongoose.js, but the compiler can't seem to find Python.

```
C:\Users\Administrator.GO-JOKE-PC>npm install mongoose
\
> kerberos@0.0.14 install C:\Users\Administrator.GO-JOKE-PC\node_modules\mon
e\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Administrator.GO-JOKE-PC\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb
e_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_
(node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node
ules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Administrator.GO-JOKE-PC\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo
s\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.1.8 node_modules\mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── muri@1.0.0
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── async@0.9.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── bson@0.4.12
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@
10)
```

C:\Users\Administrator.GO-JOKE-PC>

Comment: Did you read the error? It says "Can't find Python executable". Do you have python installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to try reading the error log.  If you looked at it you would see that it's trying to get a Python executable, but can't.  You should try installing Python.  I'm sure you could google this very error and find some good results.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!